# how are two values of different BSON types compared?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm reading [MongoDB BSON Comparison docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/).

But I couldn't understand clearly.

> When comparing values of different BSON types, MongoDB uses the following comparison order, from lowest to highest:
>
> 1. MinKey (internal type)
> 2. Null
> 3. Numbers (ints, longs, doubles, decimals)
> 4. Symbol, String
>      ...

Is there any implicit type conversion and how it works?

Could you give me a few examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no type conversion.

When two *items* are compared:

- If they have different types, the order of the types [referenced](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/) becomes the order of the *items*.
- If they have the same type, the respective values are compared, and their order becomes the order of the *items*.

Try:

```
> db.foo.insertMany([{a:1},{a:[]},{a:'1'},{a:{}},{a:true},{a:false},{a:/test/},{a:null},{a:[1]}])
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da71"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da72"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da73"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da74"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da75"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da76"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da77"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da78"),
                ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da79")
        ]
}
> db.foo.find().sort({a: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da72"), "a" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da78"), "a" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da71"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da79"), "a" : [ 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da73"), "a" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da74"), "a" : {  } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da76"), "a" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da75"), "a" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e8aeae7d11542e71728da77"), "a" : /test/ }
>
```

The behavior of the empty array does not seem to match the documentation.